# Create New Table from DBFS mount to Azure Data Lake

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, databricks

I have a directory on Azure Data Lake mountedd to an Azure Data Bricks cluster. Browsing through the file system using the CLI tools or just running dbfs utils through a notebook, I can see that there are files and data in that directory. Further - executing queries against those files is successful, data is succesfully read in and written out.

I can also successfully browse to the root of my mount ('/mnt', just because that's what the documentation used here: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake.html) in the 'Create New Table' UI (via Data -> Add Table -> DBFS).

However, there are no subdirs listed under that root directory.

Is this a quirk of DBFS? A quirk of the UI? Or do I need to reconfigure something to allow me to add tables via that UI?

Answer (score 0):

The Data UI currently is not supporting mounts, it only works for the internal DBFS. So currently there is no configuration option. If you want to use this UI for data upload (and not e. g. Storage Explorer) only solution would be to move the data afterwards from the internal DBFS to the mount dir via dbutils.fs.mv.